# selection of objects based on other objects with certain values ​that are in the same parent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hello I'm having trouble with the code I'm currently working. I'm having trouble calling selective objects based on elements with certain values ​​that are in one parent for example TR or DIV

the case is that if the execution button is pressed it will press the button on the button with the checkbox checked, the image can be seen below, and this hierarchical structure looks like this

and this hierarchical structure looks like this
[image]

```
<tr>
  <td class="custom-checkbox-td">
    <div>
     <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="inline-actions">
   <button></button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

my current code

```
<tr>
                    <?php if (!FM_READONLY): ?>
                        <td class="custom-checkbox-td">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="<?php echo $ik ?>" name="file[]" value="<?php echo fm_enc($f) ?>">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="<?php echo $ik ?>"></label>
                        </div>
                        </td><?php endif; ?>
                    <td data-sort=<?php echo fm_enc($f) ?>>
                        <div class="filename">
                        <?php
                           if (in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'ico', 'svg', 'webp', 'avif'))): ?>
                                <?php $imagePreview = fm_enc(FM_ROOT_URL . (FM_PATH != '' ? '/' . FM_PATH : '') . '/' . $f); ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $filelink ?>" data-preview-image="<?php echo $imagePreview ?>" title="<?php echo fm_enc($f) ?>">
                           <?php else: ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $filelink ?>" title="<?php echo $f ?>">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                                    <i class="<?php echo $img ?>"></i> <?php echo fm_convert_win(fm_enc($f)) ?>
                                </a>
                                <?php echo($is_link ? ' &rarr; <i>' . readlink($path . '/' . $f) . '</i>' : '') ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-order="b-<?php echo str_pad($filesize_raw, 18, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>"><span title="<?php printf('%s bytes', $filesize_raw) ?>">
                        <?php echo $filesize; ?>
                        </span></td>
                    <td data-order="b-<?php echo $modif_raw;?>"><?php echo $modif ?></td>
                    <?php if (!FM_IS_WIN && !$hide_Cols): ?>
                        <td><?php if (!FM_READONLY): ?><a title="<?php echo 'Change Permissions' ?>" href="?p=<?php echo urlencode(FM_PATH) ?>&amp;chmod=<?php echo urlencode($f) ?>"><?php echo $perms ?></a><?php else: ?><?php echo $perms ?><?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo fm_enc($owner['name'] . ':' . $group['name']) ?></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <td class="inline-actions">
                        <?php if (!FM_READONLY): ?>
                            <a title="<?php echo lng('Delete') ?>" href="?p=<?php echo urlencode(FM_PATH) ?>&amp;del=<?php echo urlencode($f) ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo lng('Delete').' '.lng('File').'?'; ?>\n \n ( <?php echo urlencode($f) ?> )');"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                            <a title="<?php echo lng('Rename') ?>" href="#" onclick="rename('<?php echo fm_enc(addslashes(FM_PATH)) ?>', '<?php echo fm_enc(addslashes($f)) ?>');return false;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
                            <a title="<?php echo lng('CopyTo') ?>..."
                               href="?p=<?php echo urlencode(FM_PATH) ?>&amp;copy=<?php echo urlencode(trim(FM_PATH . '/' . $f, '/')) ?>"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <a title="<?php echo lng('Download') ?>" href="?p=<?php echo urlencode(FM_PATH) ?>&amp;dl=<?php echo urlencode($f) ?>"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>



<button onClick="downloadSelected()">execute</button>
<script>
function downloadSelected(){
 var a = document.querySelectorAll('#btnDownload');
  for (var i=0, iLen=a.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    
    url = a[i].getAttribute("href");
    akhir = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    nama=akhir.substring(akhir.lastIndexOf('=')+1);


    if ('download' in a[i]) {
      a[i].download = nama;
    }
   
    if (a[i].click) {
      a[i].click(); 
    } else {
      $(a[i]).click();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

im resolve myproblem

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    parent=$( "input:checked" ).closest("tr");
    
    parent.css({ "border": "2px solid red"});
    
    child=parent.find("button");
    child.css({ "border": "2px solid blue"});
});
```

```css
div{
    border:2px solid gray;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="tr">
  <td>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox">
        item1
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="td">
   <button>click</button>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr">
  <td>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        item2
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="td">
   <button>click</button>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr">
  <td>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        item3
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="td">
   <button>click</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr">
  <td>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox">
        item4
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="td">
   <button>click</button>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr">
  <td>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        item5
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="td">
   <button>click</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```